# wxPython: disable multiple buttons

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a wxPython GUI which looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there are three "columns", each enclosed in a `wx.StaticBox`. I want to disable all the buttons, text box, and radio buttons within a column. I tried using `.Disable` on the static box but it had no effect. Is there an easy way to disable everything within a static box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `wx.StaticBox` is not actually a container, it's just:

> [a rectangle drawn around other panel items to denote a logical grouping of items.](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxstaticbox.html)

So, the only way you can do this with `StaticBox` is to keep track of the widgets you've logically grouped together, and call `Disable` on all of them.

Or, alternatively, you can put the widgets into any of the actual container widgets (like windows and sizers) instead, and then just `Disable` the container.

Answer (score 0):

Make the StaticBoxSizer into a class attribute if you haven't already (i.e. self.mySizer instead of just mySizer). Then you can use its GetChildren() method to return the widgets. Next you just loop through the widgets and Disable them. Something like this should do it:

```
children = self.mySizer.GetChildren()
for child in children:
   child.Disable()
```

You might have to add a check in the loop to make sure it's a button or a text control. I recommend using Python's **isinstance** for that.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a working example:**

```
"""
Demonstration on how to disable / enable all objects within a sizer
Reinhard Daemon / Austria
08.10.2019
"""
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1,
            title='Disable / Enable all Widgets within a Sizer',size=(500,200))
        self.Move((50,50))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        # layout (sizers, boxes,...):
        top_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        widget_box = wx.StaticBox(panel, id=-1,
            label='Widgets, which are controlled')
        widget_box.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")
        control_box = wx.StaticBox(panel, -1,
            label='Widgets, which controll')
        control_box.SetBackgroundColour("yellow")
        self.widget_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(widget_box, wx.HORIZONTAL)
        control_sizer = wx.StaticBoxSizer(control_box, wx.HORIZONTAL)

        # create the widgets:
        widget_1 = wx.TextCtrl(panel, value='Text 1')
        widget_2 = wx.RadioButton(panel, label='Radio 1')
        widget_3 = wx.RadioButton(panel, label='Radio 2')
        widget_4 = wx.Button(panel, label='Button 1')
        widget_disable = wx.Button(panel, label='DISABLE')
        self.widget_enable = wx.Button(panel, label='ENABLE', pos = (100,50))

        # add the widgets to the layout:
        self.widget_sizer.Add(widget_1)
        self.widget_sizer.Add(widget_2)
        self.widget_sizer.Add(widget_3)
        self.widget_sizer.Add(widget_4)
        control_sizer.Add(widget_disable)
        control_sizer.Add(self.widget_enable)

        # finalize the layout:
        top_sizer.Add(sizer=self.widget_sizer, flag=wx.CENTER | wx.EXPAND)
        top_sizer.AddSpacer(30)
        top_sizer.Add(control_sizer, 0, wx.CENTER | wx.EXPAND)
        panel.SetSizer(top_sizer)
        panel.Fit()

        # bindings:
        widget_disable.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_disable)
        self.widget_enable.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.on_button_enable)

    def on_button_disable(self, evt):
        children = self.widget_sizer.GetChildren()
        for child in children:
            print(child.GetWindow(),end='')
            try:
                child.GetWindow().Enable(False)
                print(' DISABLED')
            except:
                print(' ERROR')

    def on_button_enable(self, evt):
        children = self.widget_sizer.GetChildren()
        for child in children:
            print(child.GetWindow(),end='')
            try:
                child.GetWindow().Enable(True)
                print(' ENABLED')
            except:
                print(' ERROR')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    view1 = MainWindow()
    view1.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```